# Accessing the cells of a nested array with for loop

Tags: javascript

Working on a codecademy tutorial where I'm supposed to print out the "cells" of the table (the array within the array) like this

```
Cell Cell Cell
```

with two spaces between each cell. I'm assuming the result (for the first "row") will look like

```
Person  Age  City
```

There should be no space at the end of the "row".

I wrote the disastrous for loop below trying to follow the instructions from codecademy (copied below) but can't get it to work. Can anyone give me a hand...

```
var table = [
    ["Person",  "Age",  "City"],
    ["Sue",     22,     "San Francisco"],
    ["Joe",     45,     "Halifax"]
];

for (var r in table) {       ////// I wrote this for statement
    var c;
    var cells = table[r]; 
    var rowText = ""; 
    for(c = 0; c < cells; c++){
        rowText += table[r][c];
        if(c < cells - 1){         //only adds the space if not at end of line
            rowText += "  "; 
        }
    }

    console.log(rowText); 

}
```

**Instructions from Codecademy.com**

> We want to add another for loop and some formatting code so that we
>   can print out each of the three rows in the following format:
>
> Cell Cell Cell
>
> There should be two spaces between each of the cell values, but not at
>   the end of a line. Each row should be on a separate line.
>
> In-depth instructions are in the exercise hint.
>
> Remove the console.log statement in the body of the for loop. In the
>   body of the for loop, define a variable c. Also define a variable
>   named cells and set it equal to the length of the current row (which
>   can be found with table[r]). Define an empty string variable named
>   rowText. Make sure to set rowText is set to "". Define another for
>   loop immediately after the variables from step 2.
>
> In the first loop parameter, set c equal to 0. In the second loop
>   parameter, make sure that the loop stops after c is one less than
>   cells. In the third loop parameter, increment c. In the body of the
>   loop from step 3, append the current cell (which can be found with
>   table[r][c]) to rowText. Use an if statement to also append two space
>   characters (this is " ") to rowText if c is not the position of the
>   last cell in the row (this is true when c is less than cells - 1)
>   After the entire loop body from step 3, but inside of the loop body
>   from the last exercise, use console.log to print rowText.

Comment: `table.map(function(x){return x.join('  ')}).join('\n')` :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cells.length not cells I would think

Answer (score 0):

> make sure that the loop stops after c is one less than cells.

The instructions are a bit misleading. Really you want your `c` variable to go from 0 to one less than the length of the array.

This line: `for(c = 0; c < cells; c++){`

Should be: `for(c = 0; c < cells.length; c++){`

So if your cells array has three elements, three iterations of your loop should execute. Once with `c` equal to `0`, another where `c` is `1`, and a third where `c` is 2. The loop construct would then continue, with the `c++` statement setting `c` to 3, but then the conditional (`c < cells.length`) would be `false` because it would then be `3 < 3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = [
    ["Person",  "Age",  "City"],
    ["Sue",     22,     "San Francisco"],
    ["Joe",     45,     "Halifax"]
];

var text = "";

for( var i=0; i<table.length; i++ ){

    for( var j=0; j<table[i].length; j++ ){

        text += table[i][j];

        if( j < table[i].length-1 ){
            text += "  ";                
        }

    }        

    text += "\n";

}

console.log(text);
​
```

Yields:

```
Person  Age  City
Sue  22  San Francisco
Joe  45  Halifax
```

Answer (score 0):

> define a variable named cells and set it equal to the length of the current row

You are setting `cells` to the row itself, not its length.

```
var cells = table[r].length;
```